# How to count grouped (groupby / group) records in cakePHP with my current problem?

Tags: count, cakephp-3.0, query-builder, cakephp-3.x, pagination

By using group in cakePHP, we can get the unique records but I need to know how many records are duplicated?
I have tried **->formatResults, ->virtualFields,**

```
'fields' => array('Table.column', 'count(*) as virtualColumn'),
'group' => array('Table.column HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1'),
```

But this won't help either.
I need to get this :

> Array (
>       [A] => 10
>       [B] => 20
>       [C] => 30 )

Below is the code which worked for me :

```
$conditions = ['TableA.AnyColumn'=> $id];
$this->loadModel('TableA');

$this->TableA->belongsTo('TableB', [
    'className' => 'TableB',
    'propertyName' => 'table_b',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'joinType' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => ['TableB.any_column = TableA.any_column', 'TableB.some_other_column = TableA.some_other_column']
]);
```

------- Here I'm getting the count -------

```
$count = $this->TableA->find()->where($conditions)->group(['columnToBeGroupBy']);
$count = $count->select(['columnToBeGroupBy', 'count' => $count->func()->count('TableA.columnToBeGroupBy')])->toArray();
```

------- Here I'm getting the count -------

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['TableC' => ['fields'=>['fields required']]],
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'group' => 'TableA.columnToBeGroupBy',
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => ['TableC.modified' => 'DESC']

];

$result = $this->paginate($this->TableA);

$data['result'] = $result;
$data['pagination'] = $this->request->getParam('paging.TableA');
$data['count'] = $count;
```

Is there any other way in which I can reduce my code like using **virtual fields** or anything?

Comment: The `key => value` syntax always binds the value for casting/escaping/quoting. Use the functions builder: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions**

Comment: Thank you for response @ndm. I got the counting now. I need to attach that counting to result and return it to view and I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
$this->loadModel('Articles');
$query = $this->Articles->find()->where($conditions)->group(['anyColumn']);
$query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('Articles.anyColumn')])->toArray();

$this->paginate($query);
```

Comment: Yes thank you for responding. I did try this and this worked as I mentioned above. Let me share my paginate. Please see the question above.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

In controller in Paginator you can use like this:

```
  $itemads = $this->paginate($itemads, ['contain' => ['Departments', 'Stores'],'group'=>'upc','fields'=>array("upc_count"=>"COUNT(`upc`)")]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have already tried that so far and it's not working.